# How can I successfully register .Net 6 COM DLL with Wix 4 and HEAT

Tags: .net, windows, com, wix, wix4

I have a 32 bit DLL that I need to register with windows (i.e. register all public classes from it) to be used with COM. The DLL is supposed to be deployed using a `.msi` installer built with Wix4.

In order to register the DLL with Regsvr32.exe, I generated a companion comhost DLL by using the following option in my `.csproj` file:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

When I try to register the comhost using Regsvr32.exe, I can use the original DLL with COM. However, when harvesting the comhost DLL for registration with Wix to include in the installer, it doesn't get registered on host machines. Here is the heat harvesting option I'm using:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <HarvestFile Include="path\to\dll\dllToDeploy.comhost.dll">
    <ComponentGroupName>DllToDeployComHost</ComponentGroupName>
    <DirectoryRefId>INSTALLFOLDER</DirectoryRefId>
    <SuppressRootDirectory>true</SuppressRootDirectory>
  </HarvestFile>
</ItemGroup>
```

The generated registry entries which are added in the Windows Registry seem to be similar to other working COM Dlls.

Has any one faced this problem before? Any help is appreciated.